# EF4, Npgsql, M:M relation, "The method or operation is not implemented." :/

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I have a problem with many-to-many relation on EF4 and npgsql provider.

I have 3 tables: Order, OrderStatus and OrderStatusDict (dictionary). OrderStatus is some kind of changeLog - every order's status change is added to the OrderStatus table with its actual date and new status. **I need to get all orders, which status.OrderStatusDict.OrderStatusName == "Pending"**, so im doing this this way:

```
var lst = (from o in db.Order
           where o.OrderStatus
                       .OrderByDescending(s => s.Date)
                       .FirstOrDefault()
                       .OrdereStatusDict.OrderStatusName == "Pending"          
           select o).ToList();
```

And I get an exception:

> An error occurred while preparing the
>   command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.
>   Data:{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>   Inner exception: {"The method or
>   operation is not implemented."}

And it looks that OrderByDescending kills my query, cause if I comment

```
.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date)
```

Everything works fine, but I get the oldest OrderStatus from db :/

Can u help me? Is this a provider's cause or EF problem? Do you have any ideas I could gain this other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't write the query that way.

Try:

```
var lst = (from o in db.Order
           let maxDate = o.OrderStatus.Max(s => s.Date)
           where o.OrderStatus.Any(s => s.Date == MaxDate 
                                        && s.OrdereStatusDict.OrderStatusName.Equals("Pending", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           select o).ToList();
```

I'm guessing the status comparison should be case-insensitive.

Note that my query behaves differently than yours if the max date is not unique. I'm guessing it's either unique or that my way is right.

Comment: Thanks Craig, u've saved few hours of my work :) I really appreciate your help!